# php shell_exec touch redirect and adduser

Tags: php, file-io, shell-exec

I am trying to ultimately use php's `shell_exec` function to create new Linux users. I am, however, running into problems even with the debugging. Here is my code

```
<?PHP 

function adduser($username,$password,$server){ 
    try{
        //3 debug statements
        $output=shell_exec("pwd"); 
        echo $output;
       shell_exec("touch test.txt");

        //3 debug statements are requested by Christian
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r(execute('pwd'));
        print_r(execute('touch test.txt'));

        //actuall code
        $output=shell_exec("ssh root@$server \"adduser $username; echo $password | passwd $username --stdin\"");
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo 'could not add user '.$e->getMessage();
    }
} 

$servers = array('192.168.1.8'); 

foreach($servers as $server){ 
    echo $_GET['USER']."   ".$_GET['PASSWORD'];
    adduser($_GET['USER'],$_GET['PASSWORD'],$server); 
}
```

The `try-catch` statements don't do anything, leading me to believe that shell errors are not propagated as PHP errors (Python is this way also). The line `$output=shell_exec("pwd")` returns the correct directory. The line `shell_exec("touch test.txt")`, however, fails to create th file test.txt (even if I give the full path '/home/user/.../test.txt').

Needless to say, the actual code for adding users does not work also.

**EDIT** I managed to fix some of the code. The `touch test.txt` error was as a result of insufficient permissions. Apache logs in with user www-data, I simply created a home folder for that user, and made sure to touch a file in that home folder.

The addition of the three debug statements, as per Christian's requests, are however causing problems now.

**EDIT** Upon further inspection, it has to do with the inability to ssh as root when logging in as user www-data. `ssh -v` returns `debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address`. My guess is that ssh is asking that generic "would you like to permanently add xxx to known_hosts" but I can't respond. Is there anyway to manually add a user to the known hosts list?

Comment: What user is PHP being run as (shell_exec('whoami');)? Does it have permissions to start creating/touching files, or add a user?

Comment: `whoami` returned "www-data". I don't even know what that means. I am pretty sure that is APACHE specific, and not an actual user on my computer

Comment: www-data isn't an error. Apache will generally run as either 'apache', 'www-data', or 'nobody' depending on a few things (it's configurable). Apache likely lacks access to edit a file in your home directory. It can probably touch a file in /tmp though.

Comment: @preinheimer: Is there anyway around this? I know I can get around it as long as I use ssh to login back in as root (assuming I have ssh-keygen already set up), but is there a '/home/www-data/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' file?

Comment: Generally speaking I don't think apache is configured to have a login account, so there probably isn't a home directory. Try making one as root, then `su - www-data` to create your keys and copy ove.

Comment: OK Let me try making the home directory

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere, the user actually exists when I issue the following command `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f1` so this trick might actually work

Comment: excellent. Good luck, I'm also glad to read from your other comments that this isn't going to be a huge production system :)

Comment: well it's not going to be the next Windows OS =P I'm more or less just trying to get my foot in the door with Networks.

Comment: OK so it WAS a permissions problem, if I execute the command `shell_exec('touch /home/www-data/test.txt')` it creates the file.

Answer (score 1):

- Many (most?) of PHP's internal functions don't throw exceptions, they raise errors. I don't think you will ever see an exception thrown by `shell_exec()`
- I might var_dump() the return value, just to ensure you're explicitly aware of what it's returned.
- I would also suggest looking into functions like [escapeshellarg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to avoid issues with your input.

As a general case, rather than having PHP execute several commands sequentially, I write a shell script that does everything I need, then call it from PHP. There's one fewer link in the chain when debugging, and I find I a lot easier.

With regards to your SSH command itself, since apache is executing as `www-data`, how is it logging into the machine in question as root? Have you added the apache user's key to the remote machine.

Comment: I actually just tried that approach of putting the `touch test.txt` command in a single `test.sh` script and issuing the command `chmod 777`. Next I'm going to try creating a whole folder and giving it full permissions

Comment: @Christian: "Internal PHP functions mainly use Error reporting, only modern Object oriented extensions use exceptions. However, errors can be simply translated to exceptions with ErrorException." (http://ca.php.net/exceptions) unless we're arguing semantics at this point.

Comment: With regards to writing a shell script, there are many reasons why you *shouldn't do* that as well. **1** Someone might be less proficient with bash than PHP. **2** Handling individual errors is harder. **3** Not portable between different OSes.

Comment: @preinheimer - That doesn't mean any of the execution functions trigger errors, in fact, I don't remember any case. That's saying a lot since I've been using code dependent on this functionality for over a year now (it's been tested on different platforms i n different countries). **Edit** I see what you mean, but still, that's kind of unrelated.

Comment: @Christian: wrt point 3), the scripts are server side, so it should not matter whether the user is on Linux (Good), Mac (Bad), or Windows (Ugly)

Comment: @puk - What if IT Dept abruptly decide to use your awesome script on a windows box? **:)** But if that's not a requirement, fine by me. Did you try my script yet?

Comment: @Christian, I understand what you mean, it's just that i am a bit of a shell nut, and I am the only person working on this server. But I wouldn't recomend such an approach to others (ie. using Python to execute shell scripts)

Comment: @puk - Well, if that's ok with you, I won't complain.

Answer (score 1):

Please use my function [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673740/php-or-apache-exec-popen-system-and-proc-open-commands-do-not-execute-any-comm/5673872#5673872).

Run the following code and tell us its output:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(execute('pwd'));
print_r(execute('touch test.txt'));
```

**Edit:** If you want to make my script more OO oriented:

```
function execute_o($cmd,$in){
    $out=execute($cmd,$in);
    if($out['return']!=0)
        throw new Exception('Error '.$out['return'].': '.$out['stderr'].'.');
}
```

Comment: If I run either of the `print_r` statements I get the following error `GET http://192.168.1.8/add_linux_user.php?USER=aaskari&PASSWORD=1 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: What?? That shouldn't have happened. What PHP version is it? And OS? You did add my function somewhere, right?

Comment: `php -v` returns the following 
"PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jan 12 2011 16:08:14) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies"

Comment: By the way, seems that suhosin disables execution functions (shell_exec, proc_open etc).

Comment: @Christian, I don't quite understand, That is the full code. Do you need the javascript code that calls the php script?

Comment: @puk - Could you add my function to your code including my 3 lines of code above?

Comment: Added them. Also, I don't know what you mean by "suhosin"

Comment: @puk - Sorry, had to leave for the night. Suhosin's a patching system to secure PHP, it *might* disable stuff like `eval`, `shell_exec`, etc...

Comment: @Christian: Well I don't think that's the problem, as I can use `shell_exec`. I even got `ssh root@server "touch /tmp/test.txt"` to work. However, the actual command to create a new user still does not work.