# lsof works from commanline but not with PHP

Tags: php, apache, sudo

I want to check if the file was uploaded. For this I use simple:

*lsof | grep filename*

On my "index.php" I have:

exec('lsof | grep filename', $output);
print_f($output);

When the file is being copied the above *lsof* command typed in teh command line works fine, so I can determine if the file is uploaded or not.
But when I run the *index.php* on my browser it shows nothing which seems to mean that the filed is not being copied.

The weird thing is that when I add *#!/usr/bin/php* to the *index.php* and run it from the command line the result is '1'. So the PHP script works but why does not from the web page?

Is it related to the user? I copy the file as a *root* but the browser is a *www-data*

How to fix it? Please help me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache2 permission problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713633/apache2-permission-problem)

Comment: lsof is located in `sbin`, which is usually not in the path environment variable in PHP. Try accessing it with the full path, ie. `/usr/sbin/lsof`