# Is it possible to use server side PHP scripts for Specific Linux user accounts

Tags: php, file-permissions, user-accounts

I choose not to post this on SeverFault b/c that site seems to be only for the most experienced server administrators. I started a discussion about it over at [MetaStackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111013/where-to-ask-beginner-server-questions)

A while back I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697302/php-shell-exec-touch-redirect-and-adduser) about what user you log in as when you execute server side PHP scripts (in my case, from javascript/HTML) and it is www-data.

I wanted to know if it was possible to connect as another user, ie. John.Smith instead. I want to set up a website where permissions of pictures/images/text...are taken from linux instead of the SQL database (or if they are in the database, then they reflect the actual linux file permissions.

If this is impossible, or the equivalent to server heresy, are there any workarounds, like adding every user to group www-data by default.

Comment: If you trying do this due security reasons then you are in wrong way. Imagine if bad guy tricks your system and get user with super user privileges..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one suggested this in the form of an answer, I'll go ahead and do it. The solution is [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html).

> suPHP is a tool for executing PHP scripts with the permissions of
>   their owners. It consists of an Apache module (mod_suphp) and a setuid
>   root binary (suphp) that is called by the Apache module to change the
>   uid of the process executing the PHP interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does have safe mode which causes PHP to run as whoever owns the script being run, but I don't think this is what you want and as safe-mode doesn't really work very well anyway it's due to be removed from some future version of PHP

There was also an Apache extension that could be used to run PHP scripts under a specific user but I think that development on it stopped a while back.

It is also possible for PHP to run as a commandline script, in which case you can specify the user that runs the script in the usual ways you would in linux.

I suppose you could have a "stub" PHP script that runs under www-data and executes when the user visits it with their browser.  This script would determine the identity of the logged in user, then it could kick off another PHP script with exec() to do the real work.  You should be able to exec the script under the user you want.

Please note that this is only speculation on my part, I've never tried to run PHP scripts as a specific user from Apache, only from the commandline.

Comment: The command line script sounds promising, but wouldn't it be a serious security issue If someone ran their script as root?

Comment: Yes, it would, which is why you'd use the standard set of tools that Linux provides to run the script as the user you want to run the script as.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a link, or at least a name for this user specification? PHP man pages mention nothing of the sort

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#56274 suggests some techniques for using sudo from exec, you could run your worker script with sudo to get it to run as the user you want.  Be careful though of password disclosure and the like.

Comment: @GirdonM I think you were thinking of [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html) btw.

Comment: Yeah, suphp was the extension I was thinking of, but it seems to have not been updated for a couple of years at least.

Comment: I prefer to avoid programs/languages that don't have a wealth of tutorials/websites. I might have to go with this one though. My concern is with security. For example, what's stopping someone from running a script as root.

Comment: That's the problem with this approach, you've got to be very careful to verify that the user is who is they say they are, and you should only let the PHP script sudo to some Linux user that's set up with only the permissions to do the required tasks. NEVER allow sudoing to root!

Comment: the `sudo` option is definitely bad, but suPHP sounds equally awfull. I can't find any documentation on it, but it seems like if some sorry sap had a `php` script for wiping out his home directory, anyone could execute it via suPHP